# Matching sibling with certain attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath

In the following input XML, I would like to match `entryRelationship` elements with code 10 for example (or id, since either of this elements are unique).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
    <component>
        <section>
            <id test= "1"/>
            <code code="10"/>
            <entry>
                <entryRelationship>
                    <time value="first time"/>                                 
                </entryRelationship>
            </entry>
        </section>

        <section>
            <id test= "2"/>
            <code code="11"/>
            <entry>
                <entryRelationship>
                    <time value="second time"/>                             
                </entryRelationship>                                                                
            </entry>
        </section>
    </component>                        
</Document>
```

I could write a template like `xsl:template match = "Document/component/section/code[@code = '10']/entry/entryRelationship`. Problem though is that entry is not a child of code, rather a sibling. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Problem though is that entry is not a child of code, rather a sibling. How can I solve this?

Predicates can be nested.

```
<xsl:template match="section[code[@code=10]]/entry/entryRelationship">
```

Alternatively, without nesting:

```
<xsl:template match="section[code/@code=10]/entry/entryRelationship">
```

Or like this

```
<xsl:template match="code[@code=10]/../entry/entryRelationship">
```

Or like this

```
<xsl:template match="entryRelationship[../../code/@code=10]">
```

There are so many ways to express this.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I am getting the error "An attribute node (value) cannot be created after a child of the containing  element."

Comment: That has nothing at all to do with the code in my answer but is a completely separate problem.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too though it is somewhat related in the sense that I only get it after adding this template and whenever I comment it for instance, error disappears. But thanks.

Comment: You can't create attribute nodes when you have already created other child nodes in XSLT, but that's what your code tries to do. Easy to fix.

Comment: Thanks. I was also able to find out the problem of the error the error "An attribute node (value) cannot be created after a child of the containing element" and fix it.

Comment: Nice Xpath sir, plus one, congrats for 200k.

Answer (score 1):

> Problem though is that entry is not a child of code, rather a sibling. How can I solve this?

entry is a child of section with code: Therefor try:

```
 <xsl:template 
       match="Document/component/section[code/@code = '10']/entry/entryRelationship" />
```